# How do I code a button (on a simple landing page) to connect someone to a local wifi when clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, wifi

I'd like to setup a simple landing page (temporarily with WordPress, but eventually Reactjs) that will have some default text and a button. When a visitor clicks on the button, they will be connected to the local wifi.

Example: You have your wifi at home. Someone comes over and asks to connect to your wifi. Instead of providing them with the password, you direct them to the landing page, where they simply click on the "Connect to Wifi" button... and voila! They're connected to wifi.

I realize it seems like overkill, but if I can build a landing page to do this, I can then replicate this process for others... which is exactly what I need to be able to do for a project I'm working on.

I hope I provided enough context to explain what I'm attempting to do. Appreciate any suggestions/instructions, in advance.

I realize there are 2 simply ways of doing this:

1. Just give them the password and have them enter it on their phone, after they've selected the wifi network.
2. Just program a NFC tag with the network and password, so when someone taps the tag, it connects them.

Both make sense, but again, this is for a bigger project. I'm actually using NFC tags, but instead of programming them to connect to wifi automatically, I'm going to program them to to launch a landing page. From the landing page, they'll connect after clicking the button (similar to starbucks or other places that offer free wifi... except I don't need a captive portal, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript you can have very deep access to a device by now. However, connecting to a WiFi is not possible through the web browser. That kind of low level access could easily be abused.

Another idea for a large scale implementation would be to use QR codes that people can scan to connect to the WiFi. Still - you can't use QR codes to direct them to a website that has your desired button.

I'd rather do it as a comment but as of now I'm not able to (cause I don't have 50 reputaion yet).

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Appreciate your response.